# iOS - Dynamically include/ exclude libraries at compile/build time

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, cocoapods, swift-package-manager

### Use Case:

- I am writing a helper library at the organisation level.
- The library abstracts the implementation of a certain feature from the client Apps.
- There are 'N' different ways to implement the feature.
- Each of these different implementations might be dependent on other libraries/frameworks/SDKs which will be added via dependency management.
- The client Apps can use the helper library which is being built
  and specify which flavour of the implementation needs to be injected.

### The Challenge:

- As stated above the various implementations will be dependent on
  other libraries/frameworks/SDKs which will be added via dependency
  management.
- The eventual client App will concretise and inject only 1 specific
  implementation.
- Hence, it would need only the dependencies for that 1 specific
  implementation I want to ensure that the dependencies for other
  implementations are not included in the build.

### Possible Solution:

I could create multiple repos for the helper library and client App can install only the specific concretization it is interested in.

### Need more Elegant Solution:

I need something more graceful. If it is possible to tweak the compile sources at build time via a bundle variable it would be ideal.

Comment: Do not know how complicated your implementations are, but have you looked into using ```#if canImport```?

Comment: Hey @ZachtheBoB The idea is to install all the dependencies but include only the necessary ones for compilation to reduce the App size. I get the impression that if we are using #ifcanimport, the developer would need to have sorted the installation out manually. This is the overhead which we are trying to eliminate by controlling this from a bundle variable/scheme/environment flag.